# how to get text after a certain comma on C#?

Tags: c#, csv, split, trim

Ok guys so I've got this issue that is driving me nuts, lets say that I've got a string like this `"aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg"` (with out the double quotes) and all that I want to get is a sub-string from it, something like `"ddd,eee,fff,ggg"`.

I also have to say that there's a lot of information and not all the strings look the same so i kind off need something generic.

thank you!

Comment: So whats the problem with .SubString / .Split ? - This is not really a question as it stands ...

Comment: i dont know about .SubString but .Split needs to get an int parameter to know which part of the String are you trying to quote, lets say the string I posted is a string variable called text, so text.Split(',')[2] will only throw a substring that'll include "ddd" but what i want to wet is "ddd,eee,fff,ggg"

Comment: `string spltText = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg";
 var subStr = spltText.Split(',');` once you get that ..then you need to access the data based on it's array position very easy.. you will need to show what code you have done now that I have provided you a simple starting point..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `stringToSplit.Split(',')`

Update:

```
var startComma = 3;    
var value = string.Join(",", stringToSplit.Split(',').Where((token, index) => index > startComma));
```

Comment: that won´t work because i want to get the rest of the string after the third comma

Comment: @OmarRayo Glad to help

Comment: The use of lambdas will decrease your program speed and is not easily read by other programs. I disagree about this being the solution.

Comment: @SethKitchen I disagree. They lambda query is not that complicated, and as for as being read by other programs...please elaborate. It is my opinion that lambdas are a powerful tool provided by C#, and like all things, if misused could lead to slower performance. Could you provide more information on your statement? Benchmark your solution and mine...you could be right. But I like single line solutions.

Comment: "if misused could lead to slower performance" should be part of your answer. "But I like single line solutions" is exactly what I mean by not easily read. Without reading this post, I would need to run your code to understand what it was doing. Just because it is easy for the original programmer does not mean it is easy for coworkers especially in a huge program.

Answer (score 1):

One way using split with a limit;

```
string str = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg";

int skip = 3;

string result = str.Split(new[] { ',' }, skip + 1)[skip];

// = "ddd,eee,fff,ggg"
```

Comment: The better answer, for sure! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if all things between the commas are 3 length. If they are I would use choice 2. If they are all different, choice 1. A third choice would be choice 2 but implement .IndexOf(",") several times.

Two choices:

```
string yourString="aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg";
string[] partsOfString=yourString.Split(','); //Gives you an array were partsOfString[0] is "aaa" and partsOfString[1] is "bbb"
string trimmed=partsOfString[3]+","+partsOfString[4]+","+partsOfString[5]+","+partsOfSting[6];
```

OR

```
//Prints "ddd,eee,fff,ggg"
string trimmed=yourString.Substring(12,14) //Gets the 12th character of your string and goes 14 more characters.
```

Comment: i think I'm not explaining myself, a got to say that i need the rest of the string "ddd,eee,fff,ggg" to be in a single variable